# Spring JPA Select by foreign key in paging repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have the entities `Diary` and `User` and the paging repository `DiaryRepository` (super: `PagingAndSortingRepository`). A user can have zero or many diaries. Now I would like to add a method to the `DiaryRepository` to get all diaries by the given user parameter with paging.

My code:

User linking in the `Diary` entity:

```java
@ManyToOne
private User user;

public User getUser() {
  return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
  this.user = user;
}
```

My try (inside my `DiaryRepository`):

```java
@Repository
public interface DiaryRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {

  Page<Diary> findAllByUser(User user, Pageable pageable);
}
```

My try always returns no diaries. Is there an another method filter? Or how can I use the `@Query` by using paging.

Comment: Not sure what you mean so I think no, I didn't.

Comment: Can you show how you are calling findAllByUser. This should have worked.

Comment: Just to let you know that Page starts from 0 in Pageable object. you sure you have not set page anything other than zero ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that entities posted are incomplete to diagnose the root cause.
Can you please update the question with entities definition?

Comment: @Faizan Burney Yep, that's it! Hahaha I've completely missed that and so I thought that page 1 is page 1 but page 0 is the first page. Thank you!